# Assume $f(z)=f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$. Prove that the Jacobian of Cauchy-Riemann components is $|f'(z)|^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

So the exact J is labeled as follows:
$$
        \begin{matrix}
        u_{x} & u_{y} & \\
        v_{x} & v_{y} & \\
       \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

And the jacobin is det(J).  Obviously that is $u_{x} v_{y}-u_{y} v_{x}$.  By CR equation we can substitute their equivalent as: $-u_{x} u_{x}-v_{x} v_{x}$.

To finish this proof we need to just match $|f'(z)|^2$. I'm not so sure how I would do this part.  I know its the magnitude so its basically you have partial derivatives squared of the imaginary and real coefficients but you also have to use chain rule here and I'm not sure how to get it into the form as listed above.  Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

Use Cauchy-Riemann to write $u_xv_y-u_yv_x$ as $u_xu_x+v_xv_x$ and remember that $f'(x)=\partial f/\partial x.$

$$f'(z)=\lim_{h\to 0}{f(z+h)-f(z)\over h}$$. Because $h\in\Bbb C$ it is a two variable limit in $x$ and $y$. So if this limit exists, it exists in any direction, particulary along the real axis. So,

$$f'(x,y)=\lim_{h\to 0}{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)\over h}={\partial f\over\partial x}.$$

So, 
$$u_xv_y-u_yv_x=u_xu_x-u_yv_x=u_x^2+v_xv_x=u_x^2+v_x^2=|f_x(z)|^2=|f'(z)|^2.$$

Comment: Can you perhaps write it out?  I think that will clarify my thinking.

Answer (score 0):

$f'= u_x +i v_x \\ f'^{-}= u_x -i v_x \\ {|f'|}^2= f' f'^{-}\\{|f'|}^2=u_x^2+v_x^2$